# how to add items into listview dynamically in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having list view .It having columns "FirmName" "AccountNo" "Amount".I am taking values from textboxes, not from database.
Actually my question is, **"How to add items into my listview from textboxes dynamically when i click button"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [**ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Add Method (ListViewItem)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a7fwahe.aspx) and [**ListViewItem Constructor (String[])**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f.aspx)

As in :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    listView1.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(new[] { 
            txtFirmName.Text, txtAccountNo.Text, txtAmount.Text }));
}
```